# How does one find the Fisher Information of a MLE?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

**The Statement of the Problem:**

Suppose that $Y_1, Y_2, \ldots, Y_n$ constitute a random sample of size $n$ from an exponential distribution with mean $\theta$. Find a $100(1-\alpha)\%$ confidence interval for $\theta$.

**Where I Am:**

I suppose that what I am to do here is construct a CI of the form

$$ \hat \theta \pm z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{nI(\hat \theta_\text{mle})}}.$$

Well, I found $\hat \theta_\text{mle}$ (where $\theta = 1/\lambda \implies \lambda = 1/\theta)$:

$$ \hat \theta_\text{mle} = n\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i.$$

But how do I find the Fisher Information of this MLE?

I have in my notes that

$$ \hat \theta_\text{mle} \approx N\left(\theta_0, \frac{1}{nI(\theta_0)}\right) $$

which I assume I'm supposed to use... but I'm not sure what this is saying. Do I have to find the Fisher information of a normal distribution with these parameters? That... doesn't make sense to me. If anyone could shed some light on this, I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: You'd find Fisher information of the exponential distribution, not the normal distribution, but ultimately you approximate distribution of the average of independent exponentially distributed random variables with a normal distribution that has the same expected value and the same variance. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Ah, I see... I think. So, I need to find the Fisher information of my (re-parameterized) exponential distribution, i.e. $\frac{1}{\theta}exp(\frac{-y}{\theta})$, then?

Comment: Yes. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Got it. Thanks, Michael!